# Transposing Lemma for n x n determinants

Tags: determinant

Given real numbers $\,x_1,\dots,x_n,\,$
real functions $\,\phi_0,\dots,\phi_{n-1},\,$
and $\,\varphi_0,\dots,\varphi_{n-1},\,$
I have to prove the following lemma:

$$\det[\phi_{j-1}(x_k)]\det[\varphi_{j-1}(x_k)] = \det[\sum_{m=1}^n \phi_{m-1}(x_j)\varphi_{m-1}(x_k)].$$
The RHS is determinant of the sum of rank $1$ matrices.

Can someone help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ask about the identity
$$\det[\phi_{j-1}(x_k)]\det[\varphi_{j-1}(x_k)] = \det[\sum_{m=1}^n \phi_{m-1}(x_j)\varphi_{m-1}(x_k)] .$$
Define the $\,n\times n\,$matrices
$$ A := \{ \phi_{j-1}(x_k)\}_{j,k=1}^n,\quad
B := \{ \varphi_{j-1}(x_k)\}_{j,k=1}^n,\\
C := \{ \sum_{m=1}^n \phi_{m-1}(x_j)\varphi_{m-1}(x_k)\}_{j,k=1}^n. $$
Since $\, C = A^T B \,$ by definition of matrix
multiplication, using properties of determinants
we get
$$\det[A]\det[B] = \det[A^T]\det[B] =
\det[A^T B] = \det[C] $$ which is the identity in question.